# Using GPU Speeding up monte carlo simulation in python

Tags: python, montecarlo

The code I have uses monte carlo techniques to plot points where an electron would be found around a hydrogen atom but when it comes to plotting this the program can take upwards of a few hours to produce the graph I've been looking at ways to reduce this time and have tried using numba I don't know if I'm using it correctly but it hasn't made any difference

can someone please help me

```
from scipy.special import genlaguerre, sph_harm
from numpy import random, linspace, sqrt, pi, arccos, exp
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, figure, show
from numba import jit

n = 2
l = 1
m = -1

Lx = 3*10**-9
Ly = Lx

a_0 = 5.29*10**-11

x = linspace(0,Lx, 100000)
fi = linspace(0,2*pi, 100000)


def fact(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return x*fact(x-1)

def row(r):
    return (2*r)/(n*a_0)

def Hydrograd(r):
    return -1*sqrt((2/(n*a_0))**3*(fact(n - l- 1))/(2*n*(fact(n+l))**3))*exp(-1*row(r)/2)*row(r)**l*genlaguerre(n-l-1, 2*l+1)(row(r))

def Hydrogsph(theta, phi):
    return sph_harm(m,l,theta,phi).real

@jit
def HydroFunc(r,theta, phi):
    return abs(Hydrograd(r))**2*abs(Hydrogsph(theta, phi))**2

def rFinder(x,y,z):
    return sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)

def phiFinder(x,y,z):
    return arccos(x/rFinder(x,y,z))

i = 0
p = 50
@jit
def monty(Lx,Ly,x,fi):
    i = 0
    p = 50
    X = []
    Y = []
    while i < p:
        xr = random.uniform(-Lx,Lx)
        yr = random.uniform(-Ly,Ly)
        if HydroFunc(rFinder(xr,yr,0),0,phiFinder(xr,yr,0))>random.uniform(0,max(HydroFunc(x,0,fi))/100):
            X.append(xr)
            Y.append(yr)
            i += 1
            print(i)
    figure()
    plot(X,Y,'.')
    show()

monty(Lx,Ly,x,fi)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just had a quick play and noticed that:

```
max(HydroFunc(x,0,fi))/100
```

looks constant.

you could therefore change your `monty` function to do:

```
def monty(Lx,Ly,x,fi):
    rmax = max(HydroFunc(x,0,fi)) / 100
    # ...
        if HydroFunc(rFinder(xr,yr,0),0,phiFinder(xr,yr,0)) > random.uniform(0, rmax):
```

this speeds things up a lot for me.  I notice you're doing other redundant calculations, e.g. `phiFinder` calls `rFinder` while you call outside with the same parameters.

your rejection rate is also very high, you could maybe look at shrinking your proposal distribution.  a markov-chain algorithm might help as well, e.g:

```
def mcmc(sigma, nsamples):
    rmax = max(HydroFunc(x, 0, fi)) / 100
    x1, y1 = 1e-9, 1e-9
    p1 = min(rmax, HydroFunc(rFinder(x1,y1,0),0,phiFinder(x1,y1,0)))
    for _ in range(nsamples):
        x2, y2 = random.normal([x1, y1], scale=sigma)
        p2 = min(rmax, HydroFunc(rFinder(x2,y2,0),0,phiFinder(x2,y2,0)))
        if p2 / p1 > random.uniform():
            x1, y1, p1 = x2, y2, p2
        yield x1, y1
```

gives me 100k (auto-correlated) samples in ~15 seconds, while it would take ~350 seconds to get the same from your method (after moving that `rmax` calculation out of the inner loop).  as far as I can tell this samples from the same distribution, e.g. I run and plot with:

```
out = np.array(list(mcmc(8e-10, 100000)))

# thin out the chain to reduce autocorrelation
ii = range(0, len(out), 5)
plt.scatter(out[ii,0], out[ii,1], 10, edgecolor='none', alpha=0.1)
plt.xlim(-1e-9, 1e-9)
plt.ylim(-1e-9, 1e-9)
```

giving me:
[image: mcmc output]

(the orange points are 50 samples from your original implementation that took 30 seconds)

I've just updated to LLVM 9 so numba doesn't work for me at the moment, but I'd suggest looking at https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/5minguide.html to figure out what it's doing.  I've previously found the `nopython=True` switch to be very useful.